# i have tried to solve 2 sum problem in leetcode using hash in c programming

Tags: c

```
#define size 500000
struct pair{
    int value;
    int loc;
};
int hash_func(int v){
    int index = v % size;
    return index< 0? index+size: index; 
}
struct pair *table(struct pair *hash,int num,int loc){
    hash[hash_func(num)].value=num;
    hash[hash_func(num)].loc=loc; 
    return hash;
}
int twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    * returnSize=2;
    int i;
    int res[2];
    struct pair hash[size];
    //table(hash,nums,numsSize);
    for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        int q=target-nums[i];
        if(hash[hash_func(q)].value==q){
            res[0]=i;
            res[1]=hash[hash_func(q)].loc;
        }
        table(hash,nums[i],i);
    }
   return res; 
}
```

but i got 'Line 207: Char 3: runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int' [**Serializer**.c]'.please help me to solve.but i did not understand error.

Comment: you cannot use hash table without resolving collisions. Note that `1` and `500001` maps to same bucket and one overwrite another.